# Cauchy's Cours D'Analyse

Tags: reference-request

Is Cauchy's "Cauchy's Cours D'Analyse" available for free? Since I've seen Gauss' work for free and translated in internet, I'd like to know is there is an analog to Cauchy's famous work. I don't mind if it is in French, I guess I can handle it, but I'm very interested in getting it.

I've found [this](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511693328) but seems you need membership.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you're looking for [this](http://www.archive.org/details/coursdanalysede00caucgoog)

Comment: You can find everything [here](http://libgen.io/). When I say everything I really mean it.

Comment: I suggest you to look for Laurent Schwarz Cours d'analyse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cauchy's *Cours d'analyse de l'École royale polytechnique, Première partie : Analyse algébrique* is available [here](http://mathdoc.emath.fr/cgi-bin/oeitem?id=OE_CAUCHY_2_3_P5_0).
The other parts are on the same site. In French.

Comment: [Thank you](http://ragegenerator.com/images/ragebuilder-faces/Surprised-Amazed/puking-rainbows.jpg) so much. Do you know if there is an English version?

Comment: Any info on a translated version?

Comment: @Peter: An annotated English translation was published by Robert E. Bradley and Edward C. Sandifer in 2009. They've done a nice job (I have a copy of the book), but it's definitely not free: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1441905480

Comment: @Peter $110.00 !?!??!??!?!?!?!?

Comment: @Peter: Actually, 110 dollars isn't terribly high for a book such as this. (Compare with the **Handbook of Set Theory**.) What is terribly high is the 191 dollars I paid for an engineering statics textbook a couple of weeks ago. I tutor local college students and someone I've been working with for a couple of semesters needs more help with his statics course than his multivariable calculus course, and I thought it'd be interesting (for me) to review/learn the material. However, at $20 per hour, it'll take nearly 10 hours of work for me to make up for the expense (which I already have).

Answer (score 2):

http://books.google.com/books/about/Cauchy_s_Cours_d_analyse.html?id=M0or-HGe7D0C

I don't know if it is complete, but it is better than nothing.